# How to multiply all integers inside list

Tags: python, list, multiplication, scalar, elementwise-operations

Hello so I want to multiply the integers inside a list.

For example;

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l = [1*2, 2*2, 3*2]
```

output:

```
l = [2, 4, 6]
```

So I was searching online and most of the answers were regarding multiply all the integers with each other such as:

[1*2*3]

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
l = [x * 2 for x in l]
```

This goes through `l`, multiplying each element by two.

Of course, there's more than one way to do it. If you're into [lambda functions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), you can even do

```
l = map(lambda x: x * 2, l)
```

to apply the function `lambda x: x * 2` to each element in `l`. This is equivalent to:

```
def timesTwo(x):
    return x * 2

l = map(timesTwo, l)
```

Note that `map()` returns a map object, not a list, so if you really need a list afterwards you can use the `list()` function afterwards, for instance:

```
l = list(map(timesTwo, l))
```

Thanks to [Minyc510 in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446338/how-to-multiply-all-integers-inside-list/26446349#comment106637455_26446349) for this clarification.

Comment: ahh i see it does a loop. Is there any way more direct than a loop ? ( i dont know if that made sense :p)

Comment: @Ali : Although a list comprehension uses a loop it's a very efficient kind of loop, so a list comprehension is generally much faster than using an explicit `for` loop.

Comment: Note that using map with lambda functions will return a map object (an iterable). You will need to cast the result of map to a list to get the desired result. Like so: 

l = list(map(lambda x : x*2, l))

Answer (score 28):

The most pythonic way would be to use a list comprehension:

```
l = [2*x for x in l]
```

If you need to do this for a large number of integers, use `numpy` arrays:

```
l = numpy.array(l, dtype=int)*2
```

A final alternative is to use map

```
l = list(map(lambda x:2*x, l))
```

Answer (score 6):

Another functional approach which is maybe a little easier to look at than an anonymous function if you go that route is using `functools.partial` to utilize the two-parameter `operator.mul` with a fixed multiple

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> from operator import mul
>>> double = partial(mul, 2)
>>> list(map(double, [1, 2, 3]))
[2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to me is:

```
map((2).__mul__, [1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 5):

using numpy :

```
    In [1]: import numpy as np

    In [2]: nums = np.array([1,2,3])*2

    In [3]: nums.tolist()
    Out[4]: [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#multiplying each element in the list and adding it into an empty list
original = [1, 2, 3]
results = []
for num in original:
    results.append(num*2)# multiply each iterative number by 2 and add it to the empty list.

print(results)
```

Comment: @MirzaSisic basically there are so many ways to go about solving the above problem. i chose to create an empty list(results = []) so after each iteration i can add(append) the iterated number multiplied by 2 to the empty list. and finally print out the empty list which contains the iterated numbers multiplied by 2. if you still don't get it please point to specifics so i can help you. thanks

Comment: @salparadise thumbs up for the change in variable names.