# multiply a list of numbers with 10

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of numbers t. I want to multiply the numbers in the list with 10. Why does this not work?:

```
for i in t
     i = i*10
```

Why do I have to do this?:

```
for i in range(len(t)):
    t[i] = t[i]*10
```

Comment: you are overwriting a copy of each number from the list on each loop iteration. The initial list wouldn't be modified in such case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to multiply all integers inside list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446338/how-to-multiply-all-integers-inside-list)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it doesn't work because that's no the correct syntax. You could, however, clean things up a bit with  a list comprehension:

```
t = [x * 10 for x in t]
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way in Python.

The index variable (your `i`) of the `for .. in` construct is just a variable. At the start of each pass through the loop, Python assigns the corresponding value from the `in` sequence to the loop's index variable. It's as if you had a lot of copies of the loop body, and before each copy you put an assignment statement `i = t[0]`, `i = t[1]`, and so on. The index variable does not remember that it was assigned from the `in` sequence (your `t`). The index variable is not an equivalent name (an "alias") for the corresponding value of the `in` sequence. Changing the index variable does not affect the `in` sequence.

```
python -c 't = [1, 2, 3]
for i in t:
   i = 1
print t'
[1, 2, 3]
```

But you're not wrong to wonder whether it's an alias! Another language that is frequently compared with Python does work that way (quoting manual page "perlsyn"):

> If any element of LIST is an lvalue, you can modify it by modifying VAR inside the loop. Conversely, if any element of LIST is NOT an lvalue, any attempt to modify that element will fail. In other words, the foreach loop index variable is an implicit alias for each item in the list that you're looping over.

So:

```
perl -e '@t = (1, 2, 3); foreach $i (@t) { $i = 1; } print @t'
111
```